# Remove tag from text with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

A lot of questions here with similar title but I'm trying to remove the tag from the soup object itself.

I have a page that contains among other things this `div`:

```
<div id="content">
I want to keep this<br /><div id="blah">I want to remove this</div>
</div>
```

I can select `<div id="content">` with `soup.find('div', id='content')` but I want to remove the `<div id="blah">` from it.

Comment: so you want to get `<div id="content">
I want to keep this<br />
</div>` if I understand

Comment: @user3100115 correct, that is the desired content

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [**`extract`**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) if you want to  remove a tag or string from the tree.

```
In [13]: soup = BeautifulSoup("""<div id="content">
I want to keep this<br /><div id="blah">I want to remove this</div>
</div>""")

In [14]: soup = BeautifulSoup("""<div id="content">
   ....: I want to keep this<br /><div id="blah">I want to remove this</div>
   ....: </div>""")

In [15]: blah = soup.find(id='blah')

In [16]: _ = blah.extract()

In [17]: soup
Out[17]: 
<html><body><div id="content">
I want to keep this<br/>
</div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 8):

[The `Tag.decompose` method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) removes `tag` from the tree. 
So find the `div` tag:

```
div = soup.find('div', {'id':'content'})
```

Loop over all the children but the first:

```
for child in list(div)[1:]:
```

and try to decompose the children:

```
    try:
        child.decompose()
    except AttributeError: pass
```

---

```
import bs4 as bs

content = '''<div id="content">
I want to keep this<br /><div id="blah">I want to remove this</div>
</div>'''
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(content)
div = soup.find('div', {'id':'content'})
for child in list(div)[1:]:
    try:
        child.decompose()
    except AttributeError: pass
print(div)
```

yields

```
<div id="content">
I want to keep this
</div>
```

---

The equivalent using lxml would be

```
import lxml.html as LH

content = '''<div id="content">
I want to keep this<br /><div id="blah">I want to remove this</div>
</div>'''
root = LH.fromstring(content)

div = root.xpath('//div[@id="content"]')[0]
for child in div:
    div.remove(child)
print(LH.tostring(div))
```